# Installed a package through npm, get 'This dependency was not found:' error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, npm-install

I installed a package called [htmldiff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmldiff) by npm install command in my vue project.
Then I tried to import the package in one component

```js
import { diff } from 'htmldiff'; // the package didn't use default export
```

And I get this error.

```
This dependency was not found:

* htmldiff in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Editor3.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save htmldiff
```

I can see htmldiff in the project's package.json file.
I can also see that the main file was specified in htmldiff's package.json like this :

```
"main": "htmldiff.js",
```

What else should I look at?

Comment: Have you tried deleting cache with `npm cache clean`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is faulty.

In `/node_modules/htmldiff/package.json` the `main` is defined as `htmldiff.js` but that file literally does not exist. It would need to be `main: "src/htmldiff.js"`.

Comment: Oh, I overlooked the path and adding the accurate path solved the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Consider opening an issue for the package on github though. Normally it should work out of the box and the .js should be minified too!